# Versioncontrol for Magento CMS-Content

Tags: magento, content-management-system, database-migration

I'm managing a magento store. I have a live system and a dev system.

When i update

- Widgets
- Static Blocks
- CMS Pages
- Core settings

in the dev system it's always a mess to get these new configs on the livesystem. 
I already tried it with "toad" but sometimes ids/foreignkeys etc screw up.

Not to mention when multible developers have tasks which involve chanhing these things and want to work with thier local copies.

Is there a good way to transfear these settings?